# Misplaced Toast text

Tags: android, toast

After updates I've noticed my Toast text being misplaced.

[image]

Looks like margin or something? I thought it's linux issue, but after checking this issue on Windows, i've seen the same behaviour.

Comment: how is that a related problems with an IDE ?

Comment: Linux? Windows? I thought you were working on Android device

Comment: Try on a real device

Comment: It has been tested on a real device